# Display ProgressDialog in ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, dialog, fragment, progressdialog

I have a ListFragment with a custom ListView. In "onCreateView" I'm inflating the view: `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subst, container, false);`.
Now in "onActivityCreated" I'm setting the adapter and downloading some data like this:

`MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), new GetData().execute().get());`

`setListAdapter(adapter);`

Downloadiing takes its time and the user only see a white page with an ActionBar. This is very bad, so I added a ProgressDialog:

`ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);`

`MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), new  GetData().execute().get());`

`setListAdapter(adapter);`

`dialog.dismiss();`

But the ProgressDialog isn't shown. What exactly is the problem? I've inflated the view before showing the dialog...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified the code before to use create global variable

before **onPreExcute()**

```
ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);
    }
```

**onPostExcute** hide the dialog

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        dialog.hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your AsyncTask **GetData**

Show progress dialog in your **onPreExecute** method

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);
```

and dismiss the dialog in **onPostExecute**.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this but the ProgressDialog is only shown very short and before the ProgressDialog is shown, the white page is shown for one to two seconds.

Comment: I found another very simple solution. I put the adapter into the AsyncTask and now every thing works as it should. Thanks anyway!